# Trying to update a variable to be called by a function

Tags: python

To start, I am baby in terms of programming knowledge so forgive my ignorance. 
I have only gone though the six sections of my PYTHON site. I will try to be clear.

I need a variable to update and I am unsure how to do it.

```
def initiate(t):

    for i in range(5):


        expandsquare(t)

        moveturtle(t, 20)


def expandsquare(t):

    length = 40

    drawsquare(t, length)

    length = length + 40
```

I want to start length on the value 40, and then after I pass that on to
my drawsquare function, I want to increment it 40 and update length = 80 and so on.
How do I go about doing this?

Thank you for your patience and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this ?

```
def initiate(t):
    length = 40
    for i in range(5): 
        drawsquare(t, length)
        lenght += 40
        moveturtle(t, 20)
```

Comment: Thank you. This will work. I haven't learned about += yet but now I know!

Comment: @SidoniaKnight You're welcome. However, `lenght += 40` is equivalent to `lenght = length + 40`.